# Firestore not returning data to @Published variable

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a call to Firestore that grabs some data and stores to

> @published var userJournals

In another view, I go to call the variable and it's empty. I checked the data in the initial pull from firestore and the data shows and is mapped successfully. Wondering what I'm doing wrong on the other view.

#### View 1

```swift
class JournalDashLogic: ObservableObject {
  @Published var userJournals = [UserJournalEntry]()
  @Published var userJournalIDs = [String]()

  func grabUserJournals(journalID: String) {
    //grab current user
    guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
      return
    }
    FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
      .collection("users")
      .document(uid)
      .collection("userJournalEntrys")
      .document(journalID)
      .collection("items")
      .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
          print("no documents present")
          return
        }
        //map to journal entry struct
        self.userJournals = documents.map { (querySnapshot) -> UserJournalEntry in
          let data = querySnapshot.data()
          let dateCreated = data["dateCreated"] as? String ?? ""
          let dayOfWeek = data["dayOfWeek"] as? String ?? ""
          let mealCalories = data["mealCalories"] as? Int ?? 0
          let mealCarbs = data["mealCarbs"] as? Int ?? 0
          let mealFat = data["mealFat"] as? Int ?? 0
          let mealName = data["mealName"] as? String ?? ""
          let mealProtein = data["mealProtein"] as? Int ?? 0
          let MealServing = data["MealServing"] as? Int ?? 0
          let mealSaved = data["saved"] as? Bool ?? false
          let mealTiming = data["timeCreated"] as? String ?? ""

          let entry = UserJournalEntry(
            id: UUID().uuidString, mealName: mealName, mealFat: mealFat, mealCarbs: mealCarbs,
            mealProtein: mealProtein, mealCalories: mealCalories, MealServing: MealServing,
            mealSaved: mealSaved, mealTiming: mealTiming, dayOfWeek: dayOfWeek,
            totalCalories: "100", dateCreated: dateCreated)

          return entry

        }

      }
  }
}
```

#### View 2

```swift
.onAppear {

  for id in jm.userJournalIDs {
    jm.grabUserJournals(journalID: id)
  }

}
```

#### sheet presented from View 2

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $showAllJournals) {
  SavedJournalsList(savedJournalIDs: jm.userJournalIDs, savedJournals: jm.userJournals)
    .transition(transition)

}
```

#### View 3

```swift
struct SavedJournalsList: View {
  @State var savedJournalIDs: [String]
  @State var savedJournals: [UserJournalEntry]

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      ForEach(savedJournals, id: \.self) { entry in

        HStack {
          Text(entry.dateCreated).bold()
          Text("Total Calories: 3200")
            .padding(.leading, 15)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        HStack {
          Text("200 Carbs")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
          Text("250 Protein")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
          Text("100 Fat")
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        .padding(.all, 5)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

      }

      .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
      .background(.white)
      .cornerRadius(15)
      .shadow(color: Color("LighterGray"), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 8)

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: `Wondering what I'm doing wrong on the other view.`. How about showing the code
 for View1 and View2, how to declare them and how you pass the `JournalDashLogic` between them.
 Note, you probably should be using `@StateObject var jm = JournalDashLogic()`. Note in your code you set `userJournals`, but not `userJournalIDs` that you use in view2.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine updated to include more info. Thank you!

Comment: You don't show the code for View1, and View2, you only show `.onAppear`.
 Show the code of how to declare them and how you pass the `JournalDashLogic` between them.
 Also show where to call `grabUserJournals(journalID: String)`.

Comment: How do you know? `JournalDashLogic` isn't being used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function which i have created for my project

```
func lisentDocument<T:Codable>(docPath: String, model: T.Type, completion:@escaping(T?,String?) -> Void) -> ListenerRegistration? {
        let docRef = db.document(docPath)
        var listner: ListenerRegistration? = nil
        listner = docRef.addSnapshotListener { response, error in
            if error != nil {
                completion(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
                print(listner)
            }
            do {
                let data = try response?.data(as: model)
                completion(data, nil)
            } catch {
                completion(nil, FBError.someThingWentWrong.message)
            }
        }
        
        return listner
    }
```

How to use

```
lisentDocument(docPath: "Doc Path", model: [UserJournalEntry].self,
                                          completion: { data, error in
        self.userJournals = data
    })
```

**If you have Object as an response use can use model as UserJournalEntry.self**

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

1. `MealServing` is in uppercase, I think it should probably be lowercase: `mealServing`.
2. No need to map data manually, use Codable instead. See the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping)
3. you're using a view model, so no need to use `@State` properties on your vies. Use the view models instead.
4. You're iterating over the IDs in your view model and it seems like you're trying to set up a snapshot listener for each of those documents. This is inefficient, and you should instead set up a listener on the collection (or a query), and then assign the result of this to the published property `userJournals`. The documentation has an example that shows how to do this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping#handling_errors_in_live_updates). If you're interested in the code sample, check out [this repo](https://github.com/peterfriese/Swift-Firestore-Guide)